# how to show html2canvas 'canvas' in new extJS dialog/panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, html2canvas

I'm working with `html2canvas`, getting canvas value here:

```
 makeScreenshot: function(button)
 {
     debugger;
     //window.location.href = "mai lto:mail@example.org";

     html2canvas(document.body, {
         onrendered: function(canvas) {
             document.body.appendChild(canvas);
         },
         width: 600,
         height: 600
     });
 },
```

How can I present it in some window, dialog or panel of extjs?
Are there some possibilities to change a size of `screenshot`?

I want something like that! it wrong by me...

```
 makeScreenshot: function(button)
    {
        debugger;
        //window.location.href = "mai lto:mail@example.org";

        var screenshotHtml;
         html2canvas(document.body, {
             onrendered: function(canvas) {

                 screenshotHtml = document.body;

            }
        });

        var win = new Ext.Window({
            title: 'Screenshot',
            width: 1024,
            height: 640,
            resizable: true,
            autoScroll: true,
            preventBodyReset: true,
            html: screenshotHtml
        });
        win.show();
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quick [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/GjWfA/) of how I did it.

I basically converted it to a data url and set the image size.

The canvas part:

```
buttons: [{
        text: 'Login',
        handler: function (button) {
            var win = button.up('window');
            html2canvas(document.body, {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var c = win.down('form container'),
                        img = new Image();

                    img.height = 100;
                    img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                    c.getEl().dom.appendChild(img);
                }
            });
        }
    }]
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/GjWfA/1/)

You could simplify your function to:

```
makeScreenshot: function (button) {
    debugger;
    //window.location.href = "mailto:mail@example.org";

    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            new Ext.Window({
                title: 'Screenshot',
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                resizable: true,
                autoScroll: true,
                preventBodyReset: true,
                html: '<img src="' +canvas.toDataURL("image/png") +'" height="200"/>'
            }).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I resized the image and set it to `height=200` you can set a height/width to your preference like you can do for every image. Also for the fiddle I set the window to 500*400 else I couldn't see the whole window.

Comment: is it  win.down('form container'), just for you specific?? i want to show completely whole webpage.. any ideas??

Comment: The `win.down('form container')` is the container where I want to put it in. Just quick and dirty. Get the dom element of the container.

Comment: can you look please my code above, and give some advice how to get it working??

Comment: Is this what you intended? In the fiddle it captures only what's in the result part because it's in an iframe.

Comment: looks well, but me getting 
Uncaught Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18
after:                                                              html: '<img src="' +canvas.toDataURL("image/png") +'" height="200"/>'

Comment: probably a cross origin problem. If you implement it on your server you won't have to deal with those kind of issues :) http://getcontext.net/read/chrome-securityerror-dom-exception-18